# SerialPort.Write() - How to stop writing?

Tags: c#, serial-port, blocking

I am developing in C# using the `SerialPort` class.
`SerialPort.Write()` is a blocking method.
How can I exit this method when I want to stop writing? I use a thread to write.
I abort this thread when I want to stop writing but the COM port continues to write.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Sorry for my basic English.

Comment: What kind of data are you writing to the serial port?

Comment: data are ascii characters. SerialPort is writing bytes.

Comment: Have you tried setting the WriteTimeout property -- before starting the write?

Answer (score 1):

Both the Serial Port's Stream and the UART will do buffering.

The best approach would be to send small packages (lines) and interrupt the writing thread, letting the last send packages go out. If you can stop the writing in a civil manner there is also the DiscardWriteBuffer() method.

If small packages are not an option you can a least set the WriteBufferSize to something small (but > 0).

Comment: I chose the discard approach with  the breakstate approach .
in a thread :
serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
serialPort.BreakState = false;  
serialPort.write();

in another thread
serialPort.BreakState = true;           
serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();

but write throws an exception if serialPort is writing when DiscardOutBuffer

So it's your approach i choose.

Answer (score 0):

To break from the blocked condition of `SerialPort.Write()` use  `SerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer()`. This causes an `IOException` but that is ok as long as you can get out of the blocked condition cleanly.