# Serial Communication not getting stopped with port.Stop Command

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, serial-port, serial-communication

I have been trying to stop serial communication  with port.Stop and port.Dispose() but still communication doesn't stop when established once.

> > Here is my Code
> >
> > Start Method to send data continuously till port is open

```
public void Start(List<byte> RGBdata)
{           
    if (!m_port.IsOpen)
    {
        m_port.Open(); -- it fails over here when reloaded
    }           
    do
    {
        Break();
        Thread.Sleep( 5 );

        m_port.Write( new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1 );
        SendData(RGBdata);
        Thread.Sleep( 1);
    }
    while (m_port.IsOpen());
}
```

> > Break Method

```
    private void Break()
    {
        m_port.BreakState = true;
        Thread.Sleep( 1 );
        m_port.BreakState = false;

    }
```

> > SendData Method

```
    private void SendData(List<byte> data)
    {         

        m_port.Write( data.ToArray(), 0, data.Count );
    }
```

> > Stop Method

```
public void Stop()
{
    m_port.Close();

    if (m_port.IsOpen)
    {
        m_port.Close();
        m_port.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some issues with your code. Can you post the code for `SendData` and `Break` as well?

Comment: Your timing mechanism, `Thread.Sleep 1 and 5`, has really low values. Normally `Thread.Sleep` has a resolution of ~30ms.

Comment: There is no multi-threading going on in this code. Are you sure you are using multiple threads? If not `while (m_port.IsOpen());` will always be true. As a side note its better to raise a flag to indicate a stop.

Comment: Ya , that's what my issue is , I have two buttons Start and Stop functionality. On start Button it starts communication and loop continuous forever . So Even on Stop click it doesn't stop communication as it won't enter in while loop ,once established

Comment: One more thing Stefan, why stop command doesn't work and dispose , I mean it should stop communication whatever is status

Comment: Did you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you'll need a thread and a signal flag to indicate a stop condition:

First create a thread:

```
List<byte> gRGBdata;
bool stopRequested = false; //signaler flag
public void Start(List<byte> RGBdata)
{     
    gRGBdata = RGBdata; //copy to "global" variable

   //start thread
   //reset flag first
   stopRequested = false;
   Thread t = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(yourThread));
   t.Start();
}
```

And implement it:

```
public void yourThread()
{      
    if (!m_port.IsOpen)
    {
         m_port.Open(); -- it fails over here when reloaded
    }           
    do
    {
        Break();
        Thread.Sleep(50);

        m_port.Write( new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1 );
        SendData(RGBdata);
        Thread.Sleep(30);
    }
    while (!stopRequested);

    if (m_port.IsOpen)
    {
         m_port.Close();
         m_port.Dispose();
    }
}
```

At the stop command, just signal a flag:

```
public void Stop()
{
    stopRequested = true;
}
```

Be advised, the stop command only signals. The buffers will be flushed to the serial-port. If the flag is raised communication will not stop instantly but there will be no new `Send` commands until you `Start` again.

There are still a lot of issues in this code, but I hope it gives you a better understanding of the way multithreading and serial ports should be used. Basically: don't communicate with the serial port (or other singleton-like hardware components) from different threads.

WARNING: this code will fail if `Start` is called multiple times when the tread is still active.

Comment: Sure, Thank u  very much Stefam, let me try this

Comment: There are still ton's of fixes to be done, e.g.: checking a runner flag to prevent multiple thread starts. And then, preventing the fast click scenario. Maybe some `lock` statements will help you there.

Comment: No my problem exist. I have implemented everything ,i am not able to stop  communication through port . DiscardOutbuffer,DiscardInBuffer doesn't work. And whenever i try to access port again , it says Access to  COM Port is denied. I need to remove USB cable again and again to send data

Comment: You must ensure that com port closes from that thread. DiscardBuffers wont work. How much bytes do you send?

Comment: Ya Stefan, I send (512 * 3 = 1536  bytes). I tried to close with that thread but it is not accessible . For e.g           I created this thread in start method.                                                                                                       Thread t = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(yourThread));
   t.Start();                                                                                                    But when i try to t.Abort in Stop method , the thread is not accessibe as t.Abort

Comment: Don't use thread.Abort. That requires thread-abort-exception handling in the thread. Use the boolean to signal a close. 512 * 3 isn't very big, so that won't give any problems :-)

Comment: How do you initialize `m_port`? (and where?)

Comment: I intitalize at my constructor as                                        public DMX()                    {Serial Port m_port = new SerialPort("COM2",'250000',Parity bits,etc)  m_port.Handshake = Handshake.None } . Boolean flag doesn't work for me. I see that once thread starts m_port.Write ,even signalling flag doesn't stop it. I have tried it many times

Comment: if `m_port.Write` only wrtites 3 * 512 bytes at a time, the stop flag should work. So, does the debugger hit the ` while (!stopRequested);` at all? And does it hit: `stopRequested = true;`?

Comment: Yes it hit and stopRequested = true happens and also it gets exit from while loop but  >>       private void SendData(List<byte> data)
    {         

        m_port.Write( data.ToArray(), 0, data.Count );
    }    >>This Write method doesn't stop .It writes continuously and when i try to access port COM2 it says "Access is denied ", which means port is continuously used even after port.Close() happens. Thanks for your help. See similar case over here  >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768032/serialport-write-how-to-stop-writing